# How do I model circular motion around a point using only force vectors

Tags: math, geometry, game-physics

I'm trying to mod a game, and the physics engine only allows me to apply a force to an object along a vector (It'd be hard to change the velocity or position directly). My goal is to have objects rotate around the player in a circle.

My first thought was to apply a force from the object to the player at a constant magnitude, and then at each point, apply a tangent force of equal magnitude:

[image: Force vector diagram]

But the object just travels in an ever expanding spiral, since a constant acceleration is applied.

Then I thought to set the tangent force to zero once the object is at the desired radius, basically like orbital mechanics. This almost works, but the exact path is hard to predict and not always very circular at all. It often just ends up oscillating around the center point.

I have a mockup of the problem here:
https://codepen.io/mcdong/pen/PoQzEBQ

(I must add, I can't take credit for this code, I'm asking this question on behalf of a friend)

```
// Return a vector pointing from the ball to the center (normal vector relative to center)
function getVect_normalToCenter(pos) {
  return [centerPoint[0] - pos[0], centerPoint[1] - pos[1]];
}

// Return a vector perpendicular to the vector from ball to center (tangent to normal)
function getVect_tangentToNormal(normalVect) {
  // To rotate a vector 90° in R², use the linear transformation:
  //   T = [cos90° -sin90°; sin90° cos90°] = [0 -1; 1 0].
  // That is, T(v) = T*(v1, v2) = (0*v1 - 1*v2, 1*v1 + 0*v2) = (-v2, v1).
  return [-normalVect[1], normalVect[0]];
}

function applyCentripetalForce() {
  
  var v = getVect_normalToCenter(b_pos);
  const forceScale = nslider.value/100000;
 
  var vt = getVect_tangentToNormal(v);
  b_velocity[0] += v[0] * forceScale;
  b_velocity[1] += v[1] * forceScale;
  
  return v;  // returns normal vector
}

function applyTangentForce(normalVect) {
  var v = getVect_tangentToNormal(normalVect);
  const forceScale = tslider.value/100000;
  
  b_velocity[0] += v[0] * forceScale;
  b_velocity[1] += v[1] * forceScale;
  
  return v;  // returns tangent vector
}

function draw() {
  // Handle physics step, update position of ball
  b_pos[0] += b_velocity[0];
  b_pos[1] += b_velocity[1];

  
  // Apply forces and save vectors for drawing
  var v_normal = getVect_normalToCenter(b_pos);
  var v_tangent = getVect_tangentToNormal(v_normal);
  var v_normal = applyCentripetalForce();
  var v_tangent = applyTangentForce(v_normal);
}
```

Is there a way to do this using force vectors alone?

Answer (score 1):

To make circular motion, you have to provide specific acceleration value, namely (for velocity magnitude `v` and radius `R`):

```
 a = v^2 / R
```

I suspect (but have not tried) that for program implementation it is not easy to make this process robust due to discrete nature of applying the force and numerical inaccuracies.